# Multiplicar precio - cantidad en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Acudo a ustedes para ver como puedo realizar lo siguiente con `javascript`. La idea es que tengo mi dos `input type number` (cantida y precio) y quiero multiplicar los valores que se mantengan en cada `input` y mostrarlos en un tercer `input type text` de n números.

He estado buscando la forma, y mi pregunta es si los puedo hacer mediante dos arreglos donde se almacenen todas las cantidades y otro donde se manejen los precios, es posible esto?, me podrían dar alguna sugerencia, de antemano muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código, hasta el momento tengo la captura de cada item tanto de cantidad como de precio, genero la multiplicación pero el resultado lo quiero en el último `input` ($000000) de cada fila que opcion podria tomar.

```
 function cantidadProductosProPrecio(){

var preciUnitario = $(".nuevaPrecioU");
var cantidad =  $(".nuevaCantidadProducto");

var arrayPrecioUnitario = [];
var arrayCantidad = [];

for(var j=0;j<cantidad.length;j++){

    arrayCantidad.push(Number($(cantidad[j]).val()));
}

console.log("ArrayCantidad",arrayCantidad);

for(var i=0;i < preciUnitario.length;i++){

        arrayPrecioUnitario.push(Number($(preciUnitario[i]).val()));

        var multi = arrayCantidad[i] * arrayPrecioUnitario[i];

        console.log("total es: ",arrayCantidad[i]*arrayPrecioUnitario[i]);
}
console.log("ArrayPrecioUnitario",arrayPrecioUnitario);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías añadir un trozo de código para poder ayudarte a raíz de lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora.

Comment: Si es posible, pero como te han comentado, necesitamos ver parte de codigo para poder ayudarte. En este caso, si no tienes JS, seria el HTML, asi podremos aconsejarte en funcion de como tengas el HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así es como lo haría. Por favor lea los comentarios en el código

```js
let total = [];// el array de los subtotales

agregar.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  let producto = nuevoProducto.value;
  let cantidad = Number(nuevaPrecioU.value);
  let precio = Number(nuevaCantidadProducto.value);
  let subtotal = cantidad * precio;
  total.push(subtotal)
  // crea la estructura de una nueva fila de tabla
  let nuevoTR = `
  <tr>
    <td>${producto}</td>
    <td>${cantidad}</td>
    <td>${precio}</td>
    <td>${subtotal}</td>
  </tr>
`;
  //agrega la nueva fila a la tabla
  table.innerHTML += nuevoTR;
  //recalcula el total de los subtotales 
  Total.innerHTML = total.reduce(sumar);
})

// una función utilizada con reduce para calcular el total
function sumar(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

```css
table td{border:1px solid; padding:.5em;}
table{border-collapse:collapse; margin:1em 0;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nuevoProducto" value="A"></input>
<input type="number" id="nuevaPrecioU" value="1" min="1"></input>
<input type="number"  id="nuevaCantidadProducto" value="1" min="1"></input>
<button id="agregar" >+ agregar</button>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Producto</td>
    <td>cantidad</td>
    <td>precio</td>
    <td>subtotal</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Total: <span id="Total"></span></p>
```